# Slow query when adding an extra WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a query that is performing as expected when running it with one or 2 filters.
But when i add a third it seems the execution plan changes and kills performance.

query with 2 filters

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
   "ed_system"."name",
   "ed_system"."geom"::bytea,
   (
      "ed_system"."geom" <<->> ST_GeomFromEWKB('\x01010000a0e6100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::bytea)
   )
   AS "distance"
FROM
   "ed_body" 
   INNER JOIN
      "ed_system" 
      ON ("ed_body"."system_id" = "ed_system"."id") 
WHERE
   (
      ST_3DDistance("ed_system"."geom", ST_GeomFromEWKB('\x01010000a0e6100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::bytea)) < 20.0 
      AND NOT "ed_body"."ring_count" = 0
   )
ORDER BY
   "distance" ASC LIMIT 10
```

output

```
Limit  (cost=0.85..24526.33 rows=10 width=60) (actual time=17.999..34.674 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..252614946.65 rows=103001 width=60) (actual time=17.997..34.670 rows=10 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using ed_system_geom_id on ed_system  (cost=0.42..41629457.42 rows=6361500 width=64) (actual time=17.973..34.448 rows=12 loops=1)
              Order By: (geom <<->> '01010000A0E6100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::geometry)
              Filter: (st_3ddistance(geom, '01010000A0E6100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::geometry) < '20'::double precision)
        ->  Index Scan using ed_body_system_id_0b3a29a2 on ed_body  (cost=0.43..33.15 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.015 rows=1 loops=12)
              Index Cond: (system_id = ed_system.id)
              Filter: (ring_count <> 0)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 9
Planning time: 0.557 ms
Execution time: 34.729 ms
```

query with an extra filter

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
   "ed_system"."name",
   "ed_system"."geom"::bytea,
   (
      "ed_system"."geom" <<->> ST_GeomFromEWKB('\x01010000a0e6100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::bytea)
   )
   AS "distance"
FROM
   "ed_body" 
   INNER JOIN
      "ed_system" 
      ON ("ed_body"."system_id" = "ed_system"."id") 
WHERE
   (
      ST_3DDistance("ed_system"."geom", ST_GeomFromEWKB('\x01010000a0e6100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::bytea)) < 20.0 
      AND NOT "ed_body"."ring_count" = 0
      AND "ed_body"."scoopable" = True
   )
ORDER BY
   "distance" ASC LIMIT 10
```

output:

```
Limit  (cost=0.85..84471.16 rows=10 width=60) (actual time=238721.835..238721.835 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..252549321.31 rows=29898 width=60) (actual time=238721.832..238721.832 rows=0 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using ed_system_geom_id on ed_system  (cost=0.42..41629457.42 rows=6361500 width=64) (actual time=20.292..238664.727 rows=107 loops=1)
              Order By: (geom <<->> '01010000A0E6100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::geometry)
              Filter: (st_3ddistance(geom, '01010000A0E6100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::geometry) < '20'::double precision)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 19118611
        ->  Index Scan using ed_body_system_id_0b3a29a2 on ed_body  (cost=0.43..33.15 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.532..0.532 rows=0 loops=107)
              Index Cond: (system_id = ed_system.id)
              Filter: (scoopable AND (ring_count <> 0))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 12
Planning time: 0.952 ms
Execution time: 238733.393 ms
```

Almost identical plans except that the second plan has a shitload of filtered rows on the ed_system index scan and is sssllooowww.

Which makes me think that for some reason in the second plan the planner thinks it's better to loop through the ed_body table first and filter that before filtering on the distance join.
I ran VACUUM, added extra indexes and tried a subquery but with no avail.

Any suggestions?

edit:

indexes:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ed_body_pkey ON ed_body(id int4_ops); 
CREATE INDEX ed_body_system_id_0b3a29a2 ON ed_body(system_id int4_ops); 
CREATE INDEX ed_body_test4 ON ed_body(ring_count int4_ops,scoopable bool_ops);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ed_system_pkey ON ed_system(id int4_ops); 
CREATE INDEX ed_system_geom_id ON ed_system USING GIST (geom gist_geometry_ops_nd); 
CREATE INDEX ed_system_geom_idx ON ed_system(geom btree_geometry_ops);
```

edit:

forced a index scan on the ed_system table. But is slow.

```
Index Only Scan using ed_system_geom_idx on ed_system  (cost=0.56..5581365.22 rows=358 width=4) (actual time=7.542..53948.185 rows=12 loops=1)
  Filter: ((geom && '01030000A0E6100000010000000500000000000000000024C000000000000024C000000000000024C000000000000024C0000000000000244000000000000024C0000000000000244000000000000024400000000000002440000000000000244000000000000024C0000000000000244000000000000024C000000000000024C000000000000024C0'::geometry) AND ('01010000A0E6100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::geometry && st_expand(geom, '10'::double precision)) AND _st_3ddwithin(geom, '01010000A0E6100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::geometry, '10'::double precision))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 19118706
  Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.709 ms
Execution time: 53948.245 ms
```

Comment: which indexes do you have in "ed_body" and "ed_system"?

Comment: When was the last time you ran `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the tables?

Comment: those plans look essentially identical (modulo the additional condition) to me, it's just the execution which is different...

Comment: @MilesElam Ran it before the test.

Comment: @SamMason Yeah, the big difference is I think "Rows Removed by Filter: 19118611" which tells me although almost identical something is different in the execution

Comment: @mangusta edited question with indexes

Comment: @Doc what proportion of rows are `scoopable`?  presumably it's not many hence the awkwardness.  also, I've not used the `ST_3DDistance` function before, can you confirm that PG knows to use one of your indexes when you just select on that?  e.g. `explain SELECT 1 FROM ed_system WHERE ST_3DDistance(geom, ..) < 20 LIMIT 1`

Comment: @mangusta Yeah not many, guessing 20%.
Output:
`Limit  (cost=0.00..41.63 rows=50 width=4) (actual time=19.031..29.685 rows=50 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on ed_system  (cost=0.00..5308120.40 rows=6374677 width=4) (actual time=19.028..29.674 rows=50 loops=1)
        Filter: (st_3ddistance(geom, '01010000A0E6100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::geometry) < '25'::double precision)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 26577
Planning time: 0.274 ms
Execution time: 29.731 ms`

Comment: hmm actually I don't think st_distance can use indexes. st_dwithin should but doesn't hit the index either and is even slower

Comment: not sure about the reason of removal, but that double index on (ring_count, scoopable) makes little sense - index for "not" conditions is not effective at all. have you instead tried making an index on "scoopable" only ?

Comment: I did. Made no difference.

Comment: @SamMason  That query does not tell you if it can use the index.  Because of the LIMIT 1, it might be able to use the index but still think seq scan is faster and still choose that.  Remove the LIMIT to get a reliable answer.

Comment: @jjanes yup, you're right, sorry!  I changed my query halfway through and I obviously didn't think the result through enough

Comment: @mangusta added a index only scan explain

Comment: Can you use `ST_3DDWithin(..., 20)` instead of `st_3ddistance(...)<20`?  I think those should be equivalent, but hopefully the first is indexable.  What version of PostgreSQL and postgis are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The "Order By:" in the index scan looks attractive here, but is probably is not.  You can force it not to use that by changing your order by clause to `ORDER BY "distance" + 0.0 ASC LIMIT 10`.  If this does not fix the problem, then please post the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for it, as it will at least provide us with more information that could be useful.

You said you guessed that about 20% of the rows met `"ed_body"."scoopable" = True` (why guess?  Just run the `count(*)` query and know for sure).  But the actual number of rows was reduced from some unknown value (because it stopped once it met the LIMIT), all the way down to zero.  So either they are much more rare than that, or there is a correlation which makes them rare specifically in rows that meet the other criterion.